# Inconsistent Overpass API rate-limiting between local machine and server?

Tags: openstreetmap, rate-limiting, overpass-api

Once a minute, I run the following Overpass query (incrementing the minutes accordingly):

```
[adiff:"2020-06-16T17:56:00Z","2020-06-16T17:57:00Z"];
nwr(changed:"2020-06-16T17:56:00Z","2020-06-16T17:57:00Z");
out meta geom;
```

During testing, I was running the same script on my local machine and my server. My computer can constantly get responses from the server and is rarely rate limited (maybe 2% of the time). My server, however, gets rate limited 90% of the time and rarely has a call succeed. My server has a dedicated IP and I am certain no other calls are being made to the Overpass API other than this one call per minute. Any ideas as to why the server is getting rate-limited while my local computer can complete requests as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Most overpass servers have a rate limit. The main overpass server is heavily used and will result frequently in rate limit (although they indicate that you can safely query up to 10k times per time, which is mostly not the case). Try using the kumi overpass as one alternative.
Thereby, many universities have private overpass api's, maybe you can try to contact them to ask if you can use one.
Another alternative is to create an own overpass api (not sure if that's what you are already doing).

Comment: Have you used any of the Kumi servers lately? Not one of them seems to work with the  query listed above-- the round robin endpoint returns empty XML and trying each of the individual servers results either in certificate errors, connection refused, or empty XML.

Comment: It would seem the Kumi servers are not actively maintained: https://github.com/westnordost/StreetComplete/issues/1514#issuecomment-519079726

Comment: I used a Kumi server lately, but did have some problems with it. It only ran the first time I tried. Thereafter I used a private one from a university which worked fine.

Comment: Kumi doesn't provide Attic data, which would be needed to handle an adiff type of query.

Comment: Hmm, then I think you should search for an alternative. Unfortunately, I cannot provide you with a private server.